# If cell = value then copy and paste cell below with addition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with values starting at A5 and running across to column AI, there could be any number of entries to the rows.

Row A contains an Item code (e.g. 000-0000)

I am looking to produce some code to complete the following two actions:

If column AI = yes, then copy entire row and paste below. With every copy add a sequential alphabetised letter to the code in column A (e.g. 000-0000a)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Everything i've found expands to copying to another sheet and i'm struggling to break down the code.

Thanks

Edit:

Please see below current code I have been trying to get to work which works up to the point of copying the row however fails to paste it.

```
Sub NewItems(c As Range)


Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rngNewItems As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim strPasteToSheet As String

'Used for the new worksheet we are pasting into
Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim rngNextAvailbleRow As Range

'Define the worksheet with our data
Set objWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


'Dynamically define the range to the last cell.
'This doesn't include and error handling e.g. null cells
'If we are not starting in A1, then change as appropriate
Set rngNewItems = objWorksheet.Range("A5:A" & objWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

'Now loop through all the cells in the range
For Each rngCell In rngNewItems.Cells

objWorksheet.Select

If rngCell.Value <> "Yes" Then
    'select the entire row
    rngCell.EntireRow.Select

    'copy the selection
    Selection.Copy

    'Now identify and select the new sheet to paste into
    Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1" & rngCell.Value)
    objNewSheet.Select

    'Looking at your initial question, I believe you are trying to find the next     available row
    Set rngNextAvailbleRow = objNewSheet.Range("A1:A" & objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)


    Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next rngCell

objWorksheet.Select
objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

'Can do some basic error handing here

'kill all objects
If IsObject(objWorksheet) Then Set objWorksheet = Nothing
If IsObject(rngBurnDown) Then Set rngNewItems = Nothing
If IsObject(rngCell) Then Set rngCell = Nothing
If IsObject(objNewSheet) Then Set objNewSheet = Nothing
If IsObject(rngNextAvailbleRow) Then Set rngNextAvailbleRow = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no such thing as Row A. Do you mean column A? If you are pasting below are you not overwriting the next row? This question needs to be more specific . Share some data, show the desired outcome and above all - code something and tell us what the problems are? See [ask]

Comment: Here are some ideas for the sequential lettering...https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4027-excel-increase-letter-by-one.html

Comment: Thank you @QHarr, I do indeed mean column A. I have attached the script I am currently trying to amend to work - apologies for the omission previously.

Comment: Does  Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1" & rngCell.Value) produce a valid sheet to paste to?

Comment: _"If column AI = yes, then copy entire row and paste below. With every copy add a sequential alphabetised letter to the code in column A (e.g. 000-0000a)"_, you may want to add some examples of a "before" and "after" scenarios

Comment: You are potentially referencing a new worksheet and copying one row for every column AI = Yes.... is that what is intended? See my comment before about valid sheets.    Your question, to me, implies you want to copy in the same sheet, your code, as is, does not do this but will put in other sheets (if they exist) and condition is met.

Comment: And you don't use the parameter c which this sub is called with.

Comment: Ignoring all of this...the main reason for the failure is that you are testing column A, not AI, for "Yes"  . Apologies for all the separate points. Bit stream of consciousness.

Answer (score 0):

So there are lots of things to address with your code. Many of which I have touched on. But the main thing to observe is that you are testing Column A not Column AI for the presence of "Yes" - so there may not be a match hence no copy.

As the paste destination is determined by a concatenation to create a sheet name you should have a test to ensure that sheet exists.

For testing I simply ensured a sheet called Sheet1a existed, that Sheet1 cell A5 had "a" in it, and there was a "Yes" in column AI. This could be improved but is enough to get you going.

This line is looping column A:

```
Set rngNewItems = objWorksheet.Range("A5:A" & lastRow)
```

Whereas this line is testing column AI:

```
 If rngCell.Offset(, 35).Value <> "Yes"
```

Note `<>` means Not Equal as opposed to `=`

So perhaps you wanted:

```
If rngCell.Offset(, 35).Value = "Yes"
```

Consider the following re-write.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub NewItems()  'c As Range) 'I have commented out parameter which isn't currently used.

    Dim rngBurnDown As Range ' not used but also not declared
    Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim rngNewItems As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strPasteToSheet As String
    Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowTargetSheet As Long

    Set objWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = objWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngNewItems = objWorksheet.Range("A5:A" & lastRow)

    Dim copiedRange As Range 'for union

    For Each rngCell In rngNewItems.Cells

        'Debug.Print rngCell.Address 'shows where looping

        If rngCell.Offset(, 35).Value = "Yes" Then

            Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1" & rngCell.Value)

             Dim nextTargetCell As Range

             lastRowTargetSheet = objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
             Set nextTargetCell = objNewSheet.Range("A" & lastRowTargetSheet)

             rngCell.EntireRow.Copy nextTargetCell

             Set objNewSheet = Nothing 'clear inside loop as you are setting in loop
             lastRowTargetSheet = 0
             Set nextTargetCell = Nothing

        End If

    Next rngCell

    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

As for your lettering:

There are lots of examples online to generate these. Here is one way, by @harfang, from [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27823801/Creating-Sequential-Letter-Generator-in-vba-AA-AB.html):

```
Sub List_A_to_ZZZZ()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 20 ' I have shortened this QHarr. Original end was 475254 ' ColXL("ZZZZ")
        Debug.Print Right("---" & XLcL(i), 4)
    Next i
End Sub



Function XLcL(ByVal N As Long) As String
    Do While N > 0
        XLcL = Chr(vbKeyA + (N - 1) Mod 26) & XLcL
        N = (N - 1) \ 26
    Loop
End Function

Function ColXL(ByVal abc As String) As Long
    abc = Trim(Replace(UCase(abc), "-", ""))
    Do While Len(abc)
        ColXL = ColXL * 26 + (Asc(abc) - vbKeyA + 1)
        abc = Mid(abc, 2)
    Loop
End Function
```